# Redis Node to listen to SET events and set a TTL to every request

Tags: node.js, redis, listener, node-redis, ioredis

In my Nodejs app, I use a library that sets keys in my Redis database. So, I need to listen to every request that creates/updates a key and add a `ttl` on every key (whether it already exists or not).

I have my main Redis client (that add keys to the Redis database) :

```
const redisClient = createClient({
    url: redisUrl,
    tls: {
        ca: Buffer.from(redisCertBase64, 'base64').toString('utf-8'),
    },
})
```

And I have added another client that should listen to `set` events :

```
const subscriberRedis = redisClient.duplicate()

function done(err) {
    logger.error('Notifications not active')
    if (err) {
        logger.error(err.stack || err.message || err)
    }
}

const eventType = 'notify-keyspace-events'

subscriberRedis.config('get', eventType, (err, conf) => {
    if (err) {
        logger.debug('subscriberRedis:get =>', err.message)
        return done(err)
    }
    logger.debug('conf =>', conf)
    if (conf[1].indexOf('EKx') < 0) {
        subscriberRedis.config('set', eventType, conf[1] + 'EKx', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                logger.debug('subscriberRedis:set =>', err.message)
                return done(err)
            }
        })
    }
})

const EVENT_SET = '__keyevent@0__:set'

subscriberRedis.on('message', function (channel, key) {
    switch (channel) {
        case EVENT_SET:
            logger.info('Key "' + key + '" set!')
            break
    }
})

subscriberRedis.subscribe(EVENT_SET)
```

When I run this code, I get in the logs `subscriberRedis:set => ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / PING / QUIT allowed in this context` which is logged by the `subscriberRedis.config('set',...)`

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

**EDIT**

I changed the code to this, and it's working now. However, do you think the "race condition" issue is still there when I move to production ?

```
const redisClient = createClient({
    url: redisUrl,
    tls: {
        ca: Buffer.from(redisCertBase64, 'base64').toString('utf-8'),
    },
})

/**
 * Subscriber listening to `set` events
 **/
const subscriber = redisClient.duplicate()
const EVENT_SET = '__keyevent@0__:set'

subscriber.on('message', function (channel, key) {
    switch (channel) {
        case EVENT_SET:
            redisClient.expire(key, 300)
            logger.debug('Key "'.red + key + '" set!'.yellow)
            break
    }
})
subscriber.subscribe(EVENT_SET)
```

Comment: Did you check RedisGears? It can register for any event you want and act on it, and all is running in Redis

Comment: I didn't. I'll check it out ! Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by the time you call `subscriberRedis.config('set'` your subscriberRedis has already subscribed on  `subscriberRedis.subscribe(EVENT_SET)`.

And, you can't use this connection for `subscriberRedis.config('set'` while you are subscribed.

Comment: I have updated the code :) Could you please let me know if the "race condition" is still an issue when I move to production ? Thanks !

Comment: It seems ok, I see that you only use the connection to subscribe

Comment: Yes, I tried this simple way, and it works. Every time a `set` is performed by Redis, it executes my event handler. However, I'm concerned that in Production, as the Redis DB will be heavily queried, there may be a "race condition" or does Redis have a queue mechanism that will secure this